# Unmarshal xml structure with same tags to different fields

Tags: java, jaxb

I have to read and write a XML document like:

```
<connections>
  <connection>
    <operation>add</operation>
    <node>A01</node>
    <interface>AIF01</interface>
    <node>B01</node>
    <interface>BIF01</interface>
  </connection>
<connection>
    <operation>delete</operation>
    <node>A02</node>
    <interface>AIF02</interface>
    <node>B02</node>
    <interface>BIF02</interface>
</connection>
```

So the `<node>` and `<interface>`tags has to be mapped to different fields.
Marshalling such an object is works fine, but unmarshalling is not working for me.

`<connections>` are collected by:

```
    @XmlElement(name = "connection")
    List<Connection> connections;
```

The `connection` definition is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Connection {

  @XmlElement(name = "operation")
  private Operation operation;
  @XmlElement(name = "node")
  private String sourceNode;
  @XmlElement(name = "interface")
  private String sourceInterface;
  @XmlElement(name = "node")
  private String targetNode;
  @XmlElement(name = "interface")
  private String targetInterface;
}
```

So, when I unmarshall such a xml file, `targetNode` and `targetInterface` are null, because it is mapped to `source*` fields.

Can somebody help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've mentioned that marshalling works fine... but if you have two properties mapped to one XmlElement... which one is using? is it possible that it appears to work fine because in both cases marshalling and unmarshalling the source* fields? In any case you'll probably can use an event handler method like `afterUnmarshall` to accomplish what you are expecting.

Comment: I guess, when running marshalling the JAXB is walking through the properties and using the annotated tag name. So `sourceNode` and `targetNode` is using same tag `<node>`. This way is working fine, but sure, if unmarshalling requires another implementation, I have to change the implemation, so that un- and marshalling is working. But how? :-)